# Is the psycopg connection already encrypted or does it require any additional encryption solution?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, psycopg2, psycopg3

I need to connect thought the Internet to PostgreSQL with psycopg and Python.

**My question is:** Does the psycopg connection already encrypted and safe to transmit sensitive data without additional encryption (SSH, VPN)?

Comment: You would have to setup [SSL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SSL)